# Ratio of surface area of two prisms given only volume of those prisms?

Tags: geometry, area, volume

I'm trying to help my son with a math problem that totally has me stumped, and searching online is not helping.

> Given two prisms with volume 1536 and 375, what is the ratio of their surface areas?
>
> A. 8:5
>
> B. 64:25
>
> C. 16:25
>
> D. 512:125

We can't determine the actual surface area from volume alone, and as far as I can tell the ratio of surface area to volume is not consistent across random prisms.

How do we figure out this problem?

[image: Photo of question]

FWIW, my son is 12, in the 7th grade. (and yes, this means I'm embarrassed).

Edit: More searching did give me a site with the exact same question and shows the answer is B. 64:25. Why? How?

https://quizizz.com/admin/quiz/5aea040045cff600193132c9/math-2-final-day-2

Comment: What types of Prisms? Triangular? What is the equation you use?

Comment: @Moti I filled in some more details. There's no picture or other description of the prisms. It's probably safe to assume triangular since other questions on the same page related to triangular prisms (and other shapes, but no other types of prisms).

Comment: What is missing, I think, the fact that they are similar prisms - all dimensions scaled by same value.

Comment: The answer is "not enough information" - it seems you missed this option in the site.

Comment: @Moti the site has an option to show answer, and it shows the answers i B. the question that came home with my son did not have a "Not enough information" option, even though it seems the solution requires some assumptions.

Comment: Actually, there are questions about both triangular and rectangular prisms on that page you linked. Unless “Prism” (note that it’s capitalized in the question) was defined in class to mean something more specific, IMO your son should take this to the instructor and point out why there’s not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Assume integer and rectangle prism, with the 1532 you could create 4X4X96 and 8X8X24. Calculate the surface for the two - are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is B: $64:25$

This is because, for similar shapes,

$$ (\text{surface ratio})^{1/2} =( \text{volume ratio})^{1/3}$$

i.e.

$$\left(\frac{64}{25}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{1536}{375}\right)^{1/3}$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to derive this formula of the relationship between surface area and volume given the formulas for each? I wasn't able to.

Comment: Apart from the general claim - can you provide an example? A triangular prism with base 3,4,5 and length/height 10?

Comment: for a pair of regular triangular pyramid of side a
 and b, their surface areas are $\sqrt{3}a^2$ and $\sqrt{3}b^2$, respectively. Their volumes are $a^3/(6\sqrt{2})$ and  $b^3/(6\sqrt{2})$. You could then verify the relationship. –

Comment: @SamuelNeff That the surface scales like $s^2$ and the volume scales like $s^3$ (where $s$ is the scale factor between the similar shapes) is in some sense equivalent to the statement that the shape has a 2D surface and a 3D volume. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) on fractal dimension.

Comment: This is the answer _assuming_ that the shapes are similar. From only the quiz question itself, there’s no way to determine that.

Comment: There's simply no way to get the answer without that assumption. Sadly, reading the minds of test and homework writers is a valuable skill to develop unless you enjoy arguing with teachers / professors. What I usually do in such situations (if I decide it's worth my time) is show by example that the problem isn't specific enough and then state clearly what assumptions I'm making to actually complete the problem.

Comment: In this case, any two prisms with the given volumes that are not similar will suffice to show that the problem isn't specific enough. Without assuming similarity, we can make the ratio whatever we like.